# certutil - How do I avoid user input

Tags: certutil, libreswan

I am creating a CA cert with the command below in a bash script.

```
certutil -S -x -n "MyOrg AC CA" \
  -z <(openssl rand -hex 16) \
  -s "O=MyOrg,CN=MyOrg AC CA" \
  -Z SHA512 --pss -k rsa -g 4096 -v 120  \
  -t "CT,," -d sql:"/var/lib/ipsec/nss" -2
```

However, I want to avoid the user input, but still assign Basic Constraints "CA" and "critical".

This is how I think the output from `certutil -L -d /var/lib/ipsec/nss -n "MyOrg AC CA"` should look like:

```
Signed Extensions:
    Name: Certificate Basic Constraints
    Critical: True
    Data: Is a CA with no maximum path length.
```

Furthermore, creating the host certs with this command also requires user input.

```
certutil -S -x -n "${host}" \
    -z <(openssl rand -hex 16) \
    -s "O=MyOrg,CN=${host}" \
    -Z SHA512 --pss -k rsa -g 4096 -v 60 \
    -t ",," -d sql:"/var/lib/ipsec/nss" -c "MyOrg AC CA" -1 -6 -8 "${host}"
```

How do I avoid the user input, and add the proper extensions on the command line?

The created certs are going to be used with Libreswan IPSec version 4.12, and I use Linux kernel 5.14.